# Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

im tryin to display data from json api inside my flutter app , My Error :

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

My Method:

```
List _loadedAkhbar = [];

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    const apiUrl = 'myapi';

    HttpClient client = HttpClient();
    client.autoUncompress = true;

    final HttpClientRequest request =
        await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(apiUrl + '/${widget.id}'));
    print(apiUrl + '/${widget.id}');
    request.headers
        .set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

    final String content = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(content);

    setState(() {
      _loadedAkhbar = data as List ;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
  }
```

Json Format

[image]

Any Solution to solve it Please

Answer (score 0):

Your api response is Map and your casting your map to List and that cause error, instead of this:

```
List _loadedAkhbar = [];
Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(content);

    setState(() {
      _loadedAkhbar = data as List ;
    });
```

Try this:

```
    Map _loadedAkhbar = {};
setState(() {
      _loadedAkhbar = jsonDecode(content);
    });
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: could you give me the apiUrl? so I can run it.

Comment: I want to see your api response is an a map or list of map. The sample you provide is an map. but I think the api response is not.

Answer (score 0):

This line is casting your data to a List, when it's actually a Map:

```dart
_loadedAkhbar = data as List; // ERROR
```

You probably want to change the declaration of `_loadedAkhbar`:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic>? _loadedAkhbar;
```

And remove the cast:

```dart
_loadedAkhbar = data;
```

Comment: Still same probleme

Comment: Please post your current code (after the modifications), the full error message, and the exact line that the error occurs on